# GregorianCalendar with erratic time since epoch

Tags: java, timezone, epoch, gregorian-calendar

I'm converting times to/from an external system that uses 2000.01.01 as its epoch. I require milliseconds since epoch for various calculations, so I convert between the two by using a constant (ignoring the nuances of leap seconds etc etc; my constant might not be exact, but that doesn't matter for now). Whilst testing I noticed an oddity of time conversions.

```
Calendar epoch = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Zulu"));
epoch.set(2000,Calendar.JANUARY,1,0,0,0);
System.out.println("EPOCH DIFF:"+(epoch.getTime().getTime()-946684800000L));
```

You'd think this would always give the same result. And it does if you run it in a loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println("EPOCH DIFF:"+(epoch.getTime().getTime()-946684800000L));
    }

(RESULT: -400)
```

However if you run in a new VM again and again the value keeps changing (seemingly) randomly! I just ran it 5 times in quick succession in different JVMs and get different results:

```
-276
-612
-376
-458
-573
```

I've redone the test with different timezones and get the same issue.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calendar object time have precision till millisecond. In your set `epoch.set(2000,Calendar.JANUARY,1,0,0,0)` method, the milli second value won't be reset to 0.

You can separately set the same to zero as follows to get identical difference across multiple runs

```
 epoch.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)
```

Comment: Argghh I can't believe I missed that. Thanks.